# Prove that if a function has a Hessian with zeroes on the diagonal, the function doesn't have local maxima

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

For a function who's Hessian in the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & b\\
a & 0 & c\\
b & c & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ prove that the function can not have any local maxima.

I tried to prove this by looking at the determinants of the Hessian to determine the extrema of the function. However, I did not get very far.

Comment: Are you assuming that your function is of class $C^2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes

Comment: Then your Hessian is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: The matrix is edited, but are there any further implications that a symmetric Hessian gives to this problem?

Comment: Recall that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @user619894 Yes. That is simpler than what I had in mind.

Comment: The eigenvalues are 0 and $\pm \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 -c^2}$ so it is the trace. I'm not sure how this helps though. Thanks

Comment: If the eigenvalue is $+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}$, then it has a corresponding eigenvector $h$, and if you are at $f(a)$, where $\nabla f(a) = 0$, then $f(a+ch)>f(a)$ for $c$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Essentially, there's no maxima because one of the eigenvectors is positive? What about when a = b = c = 0 and the entire matrix is just 0s?